# Combine Duplicate Sibling HTML Tags

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to parse/search/modify some HTML in Python, but I am running into issues when there are duplicate sibling tags dividing up a string.

For example the string : "“$7,500,000” with a reference to “$10,000,000”."

Duplicate Tag HTML:

```html
<font style="font-size:12pt;"></font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">$</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">7</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">,</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">500</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">,000</font>
<font style="font-size:12pt;">” with a reference to “</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">$</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">10,0</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">00,000</font>
<font style="font-size:12pt;">”.</font>
```

Desired output with combined tags:

```html
<font style="font-size:12pt;"></font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">$7,500,000</font>
<font style="font-size:12pt;">” with a reference to “</font>
<font style="font-style:italic;font-size:12pt;">$10,000,000</font>
<font style="font-size:12pt;">”.</font>
```

I have tried using Tidy HTML, but the only option I saw there was to completely remove the  tags (with the "drop-font-tags" option), which I do not want because I still want the styling the tags provide.